# PHP Server Response under 1000MS in postman, but not through device app

Tags: php, android, ios

I am not sure where to look, or what to show you. However, I can tell you a few things about my setup.

- My provider is GoDaddy, I am not on a dedicated server.
- The application is on Android and iOS.

When calling the API through postman, the response is under 1000ms (700-950ms). However, when I run the same API through the mobile application, I don't get a response for a few seconds, sometimes it just times out (which is 30 seconds). Best case, Its maybe 1000-2000ms.

Why is there a difference like this when running the API through Android and the iOS app?

Comment: Thats a good question, unfortunately not nearly enough info to begin guessing.  FYI , i typically get as-good-as if not better response times from devices, whether on wifi or on cell data.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg what code is your API writen in? I'm running off PHP.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg what about your server setup? What are you using? Could be the server, or even the code.